# Get rules table in specific format

Tags: r

I managed to get outputs from single variable `rpart` model in data frame where for each leaf node there are rules applied all the way up to the root node in rows:

```
x <- read.table(header=T, sep="", stringsAsFactors = FALSE,text="
id number operator rule
1     8.5       >=    4
2    14.5       >=    4
3     8.5       >=   10
4    14.5        <   10
5     9.5        <   10
6     8.5       >=   22
7    14.5        <   22
8     9.5       >=   22
9    12.5       >=   22
10    8.5       >=   46
11   14.5        <   46
12    9.5       >=   46
13   12.5        <   46
14   11.5        <   46
15    8.5       >=   47
16   14.5        <   47
17    9.5       >=   47
18   12.5        <   47
19   11.5       >=   47
20    8.5        <    6
21      4        <    6
22    8.5        <    7
23      4       >=    7
")
```

Rules are identified by `rule` (e.g. all rows with `rule==22` form one rule). Now I would like to transform this data in such way that I have one row per rule:

```
rule minOperator maxOperator minValue maxValue
 4   >=          NA          14.5     Inf
10   >=          <            8.5     9.5
22   >=          <           12.5     14.5
46   >=          <            9.5     11.5
47   >=          <           11.5     12.5  
 6   NA          <           -Inf      4
 7   >=          <             4      8.5
```

I see that the algorithm is like:

- for every rule

  - `minOperator` and `minValue` = row where there is maximum value for operators `>` or `>=`
  - `maxOperator` and `maxValue` = row where there is minimum value for operators `<` or `<=`

But cannot figure how to do this easily in R.

Comment: Are your sample results accurate per your description? You describe minOperator and minValue such that we look at the rows `subset(x, rule==47 & operator %in% c("<","<="))` (for rule 47) but those values are 14.5 and 12.5 and yet you have 11.5 as as the min value. Can you double check your example please?

Comment: @MrFlick Sorry, I switched sides in description. For rule 47 and `minOperator` we are looking for maximum value where operator is `>` or `>=`, which is 11.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit messy but it seems to do the trick

```
rulecollapse <- function(d, mins=c(">", ">="), maxs=c("<", "<=")) {
    mn<-which(d$operator %in% mins)[which.max(d$number[d$operator %in% mins])]
    mx<-which(d$operator %in% maxs)[which.min(d$number[d$operator %in% maxs])]
    data.frame(list(rule=d$rule[1]),
    if (length(mn)>0) {
        list(minOperator=d$operator[mn], minValue=d$number[mn])
    } else {
        list(minOperator=NA, minValue=-Inf)
    },
    if (length(mx)>0) {
        list(maxOperator=d$operator[mx], maxValue=d$number[mx])
    } else {
        list(maxOperator=NA, maxValue=Inf)
    }
    )
}

do.call(rbind, lapply(split(x, x$rule), rulecollapse))[, c(1,2,4,3,5)]
```

and it produces

```
   rule minOperator maxOperator minValue maxValue
4     4          >=        <NA>     14.5      Inf
6     6        <NA>           <     -Inf      4.0
7     7          >=           <      4.0      8.5
10   10          >=           <      8.5      9.5
22   22          >=           <     12.5     14.5
46   46          >=           <      9.5     11.5
47   47          >=           <     11.5     12.5
```

The `rulecollapse` function expects a data frame with all the rows for a single rule. It then looks for the min/max values per your description and, if not found, returns the NA/Inf values. It output another data.frame. We then use the basic `split()` command to break up your original data.frame into one for each rule, then use `lapply` to perform `rulecollapse` on each of those subsets, and finally use `do.call(rbind, ..)` to merge everything back into one data.frame.

Comment: Excellent. Would you mind to provide at least short explanation how it works? I found different solution, see my answer below.

Comment: @TomasGreif A brief explanation has been added.

Answer (score 1):

My approach:

- split data into two sets, one with > and >= operators and second with <, <= operators
- sort data frames by rule and number (asceding for <,<= and descending for >,>=)
- get first row for every rule from sorted data frames
- full outer join data frames

Code:

```
minRules <- x[x$operator %in% c('>','>='),]
maxRules <- x[x$operator %in% c('<','<='),]

merge(
  aggregate(. ~ rule, data = minRules[with(minRules, order(rule, -number)), ], 
            FUN=head, 1),
  aggregate(. ~ rule, data = maxRules[with(maxRules, order(rule, number)), ],
            FUN=head, 1),
  by = 'rule', all = TRUE
)
```

Results in:

```
  rule id.x number.x operator.x id.y number.y operator.y
1    4    2     14.5         >= <NA>     <NA>       <NA>
2    6 <NA>     <NA>       <NA>   21        4          <
3    7   23        4         >=   22      8.5          <
4   10    3      8.5         >=    5      9.5          <
5   22    9     12.5         >=    7     14.5          <
6   46   12      9.5         >=   14     11.5          <
7   47   19     11.5         >=   18     12.5          <
```